# Iterating list to create df

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a variable <class 'list'> that comes from a post request API in GraphQL that looks like this:

```
  [
    {'duration': 0, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Start form'
        }
    }, 
    {'duration': 441, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Análise do SAC - Mesas'
        }
    }, 
    {'duration': 126057, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Análise do SAC - Industrial'
        }
    }
 ]
```

How can I iterate thru this list and create a dataframe that looks like this:

| Start form | Análise do SAC - Mesas | Análise do SAC - Industrial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 441 | 126057 |

I need to create the df like this because I will merge with another df

Also, I'm curious, what's the need of this list organization? Like a list of lists? List of dict?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "what's the need"? Do you mean "what's the name"? It's a list of dictionaries.

Comment: yes, that what i meant, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code which will produce the output you want:

```
import pandas as pd

response =  [
    {'duration': 0, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Start form'
        }
    }, 
    {'duration': 441, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Análise do SAC - Mesas'
        }
    }, 
    {'duration': 126057, 
     'phase': 
        {
            'name': 'Análise do SAC - Industrial'
        }
    }
 ]
 
data = {}
for obj in response:
    data[obj["phase"]["name"]] = [obj["duration"]]
     
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(l)
df = df.set_index('phase.name').T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
phase.name  Start form  Análise do SAC - Mesas  Análise do SAC - Industrial
0                    0                     441                       126057
```

If want to rename axis you can then use:

```
df.rename_axis(None, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
   Start form  Análise do SAC - Mesas  Análise do SAC - Industrial
0           0                     441                       126057
```